# Sorting the content of file according to a field other than first character

Tags: python

I have a file `data.txt` which has content like:

```
name#age#company#gender#salary
priya#22#CGI#F#42000
sandy#12#Capgemini#M#45000
anoop#16#HP#M#5000
mahesh#14#oracle#M#36000
jai#34#oracle#M#53000
mahesh#34#oracle#M#36000
priya#22#CGI#F#42000
mahesh#24#oracle#M#36000
```

I want to read this file and write to another file sorted according to salary and removing the duplicates. I have done like this but it sorts according to the first character of the line:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as rf, open('sorte.txt','w') as wf:
   data = rf.readlines()
   data = sorted(data)
   for i in range(len(data)):
      wf.write(data[i])
```

So, how do I sort this file according to the salary?

Comment: As to the duplicates: what do you consider a duplicate? Identical entire line, or identical name is enough?

Comment: Note: for the future, you may want to look into the Pandas library, since this makes it easy to handle two-dimensional tables.

Comment: For your data, you'd want to split each line by the `#` character, e.g. `data = [line.split('#') for line in data]`, before sorting. Or turn it into a list of dicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function that will get the salary from each line (provided it's the last field and they're separated by `#`):

```
def get_salary(line):
    return line.split('#')[-1].strip()
```

And then use it as a key in `sorted`:

```
sorted(data, key=get_salary)
```

Example with your data:

```
>>> with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
...     data = f.readlines()
... 
>>> data
['name#age#company#gender#salary\n', 'priya#22#CGI#F#42000\n', 'sandy#12#Capgemini#M#45000\n', 'anoop#16#HP#M#5000\n', 'mahesh#14#oracle#M#36000\n', 'jai#34#oracle#M#53000\n', 'mahesh#34#oracle#M#36000\n', 'priya#22#CGI#F#42000\n', 'mahesh#24#oracle#M#36000\n']
>>> def get_salary(line):
...     return line.split('#')[-1].strip()
... 
>>> sorted(data, key=get_salary)
['mahesh#14#oracle#M#36000\n', 'mahesh#34#oracle#M#36000\n', 'mahesh#24#oracle#M#36000\n', 'priya#22#CGI#F#42000\n', 'priya#22#CGI#F#42000\n', 'sandy#12#Capgemini#M#45000\n', 'anoop#16#HP#M#5000\n', 'jai#34#oracle#M#53000\n', 'name#age#company#gender#salary\n']
>>>
```

As to removing the duplicates, you can use a `set` for this (it will remove the identical lines): `sorted(list(set(data)), key=get_salary)`

Comment: Thanks, man. I am bit ashamed that it was this easy.

Answer (score 2):

As sugessted split the string using `split('#')`, then use the `key` parameter of `sorted` to specifiy which column to sort.

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as rf, open('sorte.txt','w') as wf:
   data = rf.readlines()
   header = data[0]
   data = [line.split("#") for line in data[1:]]
   data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x[-1]), reverse=True)
   wf.write(header)
   for line in data:
      wf.write('#'.join(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

*Since you did not mention how you want it to be sorted, I am omitting the sorted part.*

```
with open("buffer.txt") as fp:
    heading = next(fp)
    sample = fp.readlines()

sample = [i.strip() for i in sample if i.strip()]  # removing \n

sample = sorted(sample, key=lambda x: int(x.split("#")[-1]))

with open("buffer.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(heading)
    for line in sample:
        fp.write(line + "\n")
```